# Is it normal for a hosting service to require that I buy a public IPv4 for using my own $25 certificate?

Tags: ssl, certificate, ipv4

Self explanatory title, I guess.

I'd love to have my website in https only, but they (the web hosting service) claim in the administration that I need to buy a public IPv4 address from them before installing my own certificate I bought elsewhere.

I thought x.509 certificates are not tied to IP addresses at all. Is there any technical reason for such requirement or is this just a marketing idea of making people pay for services they do not need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This restriction is due to a technical limitation in the SSL/TLS protocol.

On shared hosting, name-based virtual hosting is used to serve websites with different domain names using the same IP address. However, because the domain name is not sent in the SSL handshake (it is sent in the HTTP request after the SSL connection is established), the server cannot choose from multiple SSL certificates on a particular IP address based on the domain name. As a result, only one certificate can be used per IP address.

While [Server Name Indication](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHostsWithSNI) (SNI) circumvents this limitation by supplying the domain name in the SSL handshake, this is a relatively recent extension ([introduced in 2006](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4366.txt)) that is not universally supported. In particular, Internet Explorer on Windows XP does not support SNI. As a result, this limitation persists on many servers, and a dedicated IP address is necessary to use an SSL certificate.

Comment: Win XP is recently out of support entirely.  Is that the only OS that retains this issue?

Comment: For normal browsers: Yes, and only when using IE. Although e.g. some command line tools might not implement it as well.

Answer (score 0):

This other answer on StackOverflow can explain what's going on: from(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15783990/what-exactly-does-every-ssl-certificate-requires-a-dedicated-ip-mean)

- There's no such thing as "SSL certificate". The term is misleading. X.509 certificates can be issued for different purposes (as defined by their Key Usage and Extended Key Usage "properties"), in particular for securing SSL/TLS sessions.
- Certificates don't require anything in regards to sockets, addresses and ports as certificates are pure data.
- When securing some connection with TLS, you usually use the certificate to authenticate the server (and sometimes the client). There's one server per IP/Port, so usually there's no problem for the server to choose what certificate to use. HTTPS is the exception -- several different domain names can refer to one IP and the client (usually a browser) connects to the same server for different domain names. The domain name is passed to the server in the request, which goes after TLS handshake. Here's where the problem arises - the web server doesn't know which certificate to present. To address this a new extension has been added to TLS, named SNI (Server Name Indication). However, not all clients support it. So in general it's a good idea to have a dedicated server per IP/Port per domain. In other words, each domain, to which the client can connect using HTTPS, should have its own IP address (or different port, but that's not usual).

---

Now I personally have used certificates on an IP basis, but also on a domain basis on my servers where I have servers that use multiple certificates for multiple domains on one IP address. So, it's not necessary to have an IP per SSL cert, but it can make things a bit more secure.